# How to integrate the Sentry user feedback plugin with an angular2+ app

Tags: angular, sentry

The sentry [documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/learn/user-feedback/) does not have explicit instructions for integrating their user feedback plugin into your angular 2+ app.

How can I configure my Sentry to every time there's an error the user feedback modal pops up?

Answer (score 0):

Using Sentry's User Feedback feature with angular2+ is exactly like using it with [browser Javascript](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/usage/#javascript-user-feedback)

in the `app.module.ts` file, right after the `Raven.captureException(err);` line, add the line below and you should be good to go.

```
Raven.showReportDialog();
```

Next time there's an exception, the User Feedback modal will pop up.
This worked for both front-end and server-side (nodejs) errors for me.